# Two branch Git workflow - staging always behind and/or ahead master

Tags: git

I decided to only have two branches:

- master
- staging

and then feature branches that are taken from master and are merged into staging.

This is my scenario:

1. Created branch "update robots.txt"
2. Made some changes
3. Merged it into staging
4. Tested
5. Merged staging into master

After this I end up in the infinite loop or merges and staging being behind and/or ahead of the master. I looked at different answers but can't wrap my head around what's happening..

At one point it wasn't even merging and I ended up with something like that:

[image]

Am I even on the right track with my workflow design? I read many articles and questions on SO and seemed like I did everything as suggested. Two branches + feature branches. I am yet to understand what is happening with those merges

Comment: Use a tag for releases instead.

Comment: That's what I use for releases indeed.. here I'm having problems way before releases

Comment: On your local clone : take a look at the history of your repo -- through a GUI client, or with `git log --graph --oneline origin/master origin/staging`.

Comment: How do you perform the actions "Merged into staging" and "Merged staging into master" ?

Comment: Pull requests in Github

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a branch C off of branch A and then merging it into branch B. That makes no sense at all and goes completely against the fundamentals of what a merge is. Merging revolves around the common base, that is, the point on branch A where branch C diverged. Where the “common base” on branch B would be is anybody’s guess.  Abandon this workflow; it is untenable. If branch C is created off of branch A, merge it back to branch A.

Comment: Are you saying that my problem occurs when my feature branch is merged into a different base than the one it was created from?

Answer (score 0):

You need two changes to your workflow to achieve the [feature branch workflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/feature-branch-workflow).

- Do your testing in the feature branch before you merge.
- Track releases with tags.

Your workflow would look something like this.

1. Create feature branch.
2. Work on feature branch.
3. Update feature branch from master.
4. QA feature branch.
5. Merge it into master.

Steps 3 and 4 are the critical changes. If you keep your feature branches up to date with master, whether with `git merge master` or `git rebase master`, there is no need for a staging branch. When you QA a feature branch it is already up to date with master. And you're QAing just that change, not a whole bunch of untested changes smashed together, making the QA process much simpler.

This eliminates the need for a separate staging branch. No more managing two parallel long lived branches. There's only one, master. And because only tested branches are ever merged into master, master is always stable.

Then, whenever you like, you can tag master, deploy it to a staging server, QA it, and release it.

1. Tag master with a staging tag.
2. Deploy to a staging server.
3. QA staging.
4. Tag the staging tag as released.
5. Deploy the released tag production.

master is already stable, so the QA step here is a bit redundant. It should be used for acceptance testing, and also allow if any feature branches were merged that maybe weren't exactly up to date.

Comment: Okay, this is interesting.. I knew my Git knowledge wasn't complete but this sheds some light on how to use it. Does it mean that master is no longer what's deployed but a last release tag is what's deployed? Basically the master branch doesn't have meaning anymore if everything is done with Tags?

Comment: Branches and tags in Git are just labels which point to a commit, Git calls them "references". The commits themselves know their history. The major difference between a branch and a tag is a branch moves as you make commits and a tag does not. The master branch tracks the current collective, tested, and stable state of the project from which you can release when you like. Since they don't move, tags track what was deployed. You don't even need the tags to track staging and production deployments, you can just remember the commit ID; tags are just a convenience.

Comment: For example. When you decide you want to deploy you'd note that master is at commit abc123. You'd deploy commit abc123 to staging. Once you're satisfied you'd deploy commit abc123 ***not master*** to production. You deploy by commit ID, not by branch, because branches change, commit IDs do not. master may change between deploying to staging and production. Tags just give you a label rather than having to remember "abc123". Then you can automate it: deploy the commit tagged with staging to staging, deploy the commit tagged with production to production.

Comment: Does it mean that `staging` as a tag will only be at one place in time to basically let me know what is deployed where?

Comment: @Moseleyi Depends on how you name the tags. `staging` and `production` would tell you what is currently deployed to staging and production. If you also tag with a timestamp like `staging/2020-09-08T17:10:58Z` you know that was where staging was at at that time. Or you can tag with version numbers, `v1.2.3`. Again, you don't have to use tags, you can also track timestamps and commit IDs of deployments in a release database.

Comment: @Moseleyi Note that [Github has a tag-based release system](https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/releasing-projects-on-github).

Comment: I used them few times but I admit I didn't know the full extent of tags' "power". I recreated the branch structure so I only have master and everything I want to add will go to master. Then I will update the other feature branches with rebase/merge. Since my project is not going to be used by xx developers this system sounds like enough. It's complicated enough I can't use git on my server and have to deploy things manually :D Cheers

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221175/discussion-between-moseleyi-and-schwern).