# Git only merging some commits

Tags: git

Let's say that I have a git repository containing the following branches:

- QA
- Staging
- Master

On the QA branch I have commit 'A' which has been approved for release, I also have commit 'B' that has not been approved for release.

Is there a way for me to merge only up to commit 'A' into staging and master so that the changes not approved for release are kept out of the staging/production environments?

Comment: A lot of complexity can be avoided if you [do QA and staging with tags instead of branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63796378/two-branch-git-workflow-staging-always-behind-and-or-ahead-master/63796648#63796648).

Comment: Are commits A and B both in the QA branch? And I presume B is after A?

Comment: How did you wind up with part of the QA branch approved and part not approved? Does QA go commit-by-commit?

Comment: @Schwern, this is the result of scope not being very clearly defined.  Essentially, someone just dumped a bunch of tickets into a sprint without recognizing that not all of them should be released at the end of the sprint.  See my more detailed responses to your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "object" of a `git merge` command is always a commit. (The fact that you usually say the name of a branch is merely a contingent fact, because a branch just happens to be another name for a commit.) So, using the SHA for the commit you want to merge "only up to", just merge it.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing.  Marking this as accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

> On the QA branch I have commit 'A' which has been approved for release, I also have commit 'B' that has not been approved for release. Is there a way for me to merge only up to commit 'A' into staging and master so that the changes not approved for release are kept out of the staging/production environments?

What you're asking for demonstrates a problem with managing releases with branches: you can only have one thing in QA at a time, and they tend to pile up. A lot of complexity can be avoided if you [use the feature branch workflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/feature-branch-workflow) and [do QA and staging with tags instead of branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63796378/two-branch-git-workflow-staging-always-behind-and-or-ahead-master/63796648#63796648).

Now, to fix it in your current workflow...

You can make a feature branch off B, move QA to A, deal with QA (now at A) normally, and work on B as normal.

Here's your repo, presumably.

```
Z - A - B [QA]
 \
  C - D [staging]
       \
        E - F [master]
```

1. Make a feature branch off B...

```
$ git branch feature/B B

      [feature/B]
Z - A - B [QA]
 \
  C - D [staging]
       \
        E - F [master]
```

2. Move QA back to A.

```
$ git checkout QA
$ git reset --hard A
$ git push --force-with-lease

      B [feature/B]
     /
Z - A [QA]
 \
  C - D [staging]
       \
        E - F [master]
```

3. Release QA as normal.
4. Continue developing the feature.

Comment: I kept my question really tightly scoped, perhaps too tightly, because we do work out of feature branches, our process involves merging feature branches into QA for the purposes of well, performing QA on those features.  A decision on what features would be released hadn't been made until nearly the 11th hour so a number of features were already merged.  IMO, the real problem was one of scope but I needed to deal with the temporary problem of too many features theoretically "ready" for release at the same time.

Comment: All of that having been said in my above comment, I like the idea of using tags rather than dedicated branches, and I'll definitely research this further as I think it could be a good alternative.